# How can I get the X, and Y, coordinates of a tap on a view in Android?

Tags: android, coordinates, android-canvas

I'm working on a project and I need to get the x, and y coordinates of a tap on the Android `canvas`.

Example: When the user tap any spot on the `canvas` > 500px, a `toast` message pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

         Log.d("coords", event.getX() + " : " + event.getY();
         if(..){
             // Do stuff..
         }
     }
});
```